# At which condition do you earn exp/fame in RotMG?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

**At which condition do you earn exp/fame from monster kill in RotMG?** From fame-train practice I know that you don't need even to hit a monster to earn fame. But you do not earn fame from all gods killed over a realm. So there should be something like **maximum distance to killed god condition. What is this distance?**

Additional question would be: Do you earn fame if you killed the god, with poison for example, but was far away from it? What if you just hit it once?

Answer (score 1):

> At which condition do you earn exp/fame from monster kill in RotMG?

If you got EXP from it, you earned fame. If you are in the area of a kill, even if you did not participate in killing it, you get EXP. From the [[wiki]](http://realmofthemadgod.wikia.com/wiki/Fame): `Fame can be gathered from defeating monsters. The harder the monsters you fight, the faster you gain fame.` If you want more proof than that, remembering that fame is VERY little of the percent of EXP, compare your fame before and after attacking a large number of low-level monsters (sometimes you can find swarms of them). Also, :

> From fame-train practice I know that you don't need even to hit a monster to earn fame.

There is a fame bonus to this effect [(Pacifist).](https://www.realmeye.com/wiki/fame-bonuses)

> But you do not earn fame from all gods killed over a realm. So there should be something like maximum distance to killed god condition. What is this distance?

I'm sorry, I misread this question. I'm not aware of if anyone has calculated what the exact distance is, but I personally would guess it's somwhere around a max distance of 1-2 "screens" away.

> Do you earn fame if you killed the god, with poison for example, but was far away from it?

If you are too far away from a monster when it dies, you do not get EXP.

> What if you just hit it once?

Does not matter if you hit it 0 times, 1 time, or 10000 times, you still get fame if you are in range.